# Open dialog box for name and file type to be created MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, dialog, save

I try create a .txt file with define name in dialog box when click in button Export Parameters (gui Matlab) but can not.
Only can create new file with names already defined, as we see in the following code.

```
function export_par_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
f=handles.f;
d=handles.d;
gamma=handles.gamma;

dlmwrite('PARAMETERS.txt', [f',gamma',abs(d)',imag(d)'], 'delimiter', '\t','newline','pc')
```

[f',gamma',abs(d)',imag(d)'] is a simple matrix

I only need the dialog box before saving nem file

Answer (score 2):

please read the documentation of [uiputfile](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/uiputfile.html)